# What is this qemu-system-aarch64 process and why is it using almost 3 GB of RAM on my M1 Mac

Tags: macos, mac-mini, big-sur, activity-monitor, apple-silicon

I am on my M1 Mac mini (Big Sur 11.3.1). I got a message that I am running out of RAM and should close some apps. I saw this process called `qemu-system-aarch64` that takes up to 3GB of RAM. I don't know what it does and cannot stop it either. What is it and why does it eat up so much RAM?

[image]

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This process belongs to an application you've installed yourself.

To find out more, select the process in Activity Monitor and press <kbd>Cmd-I</kbd> to open the Process Information window. You should see the name of the process which started it at the top, and the path to the binary itself near the top of the 3rd tab (open files and ports).

Comment: @Neekey this guy explains it well https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/memory-vs-real-memory.1749505/?post=19295944#post-19295944

Comment: In my case it was [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima)

Comment: "This process belongs to an application you've installed yourself" Ah! Thanks!

Answer (score 156):

It was **Docker for Mac**!

There is no clear name indication that this is a Docker process, so you can't clearly spot it in the Activity Monitor unless you use `View -> All Processes, Hierarchically` or view the process origin with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Stopping Docker releases the resources.

[Github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5812)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, indeed it was docker. I guess this process is needed because of docker's support for multi-arch images.

Comment: It's possible to see process origin by hitting `⌘`+`I`

Comment: Reference confirming this answer: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5812

Comment: thanks @dbaltor! updated the answer

Comment: @Community this bot needs to be updated - This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are a developer and you are using some sort of Android emulator. I too have a Mac, and this process refers to the Android Studio emulator I use for debugging.

Comment: Please note that the OP commented on the accepted answer that they are a developer and had installed Docker.

Comment: But not everyone landing on the result will be a developer working with Docker. So this answer is just fine. There is no need to down vote.

Comment: Indeed, on my machine it was also coming from the Android emulator.